# SSL error WSO2API manager

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, wso2

I have set up WSO2API manager on EC2 server and using nginx for serving requests.

If I access https://example.com/carbon with my domain ssl, it works fine. and I got the verified indication on browser URL.

But when i access https://example.com:9443/store/forum it gives me SSL error at the top. When I investigate the issue i found "Common name as localhost"

[image]

How to solve this issues?

Comment: Are you using default keystore shipped with the product or did you changed the keystore used by the API Manager?

Comment: I didnt changed any keystore. Basically I am using certificate at nginx level.

Comment: which version of API Manager you are using?

Comment: 1.7.0 ..

I have am using ssl certificate at nginx level.